# MySQL Can Connect Remotely but not Locally

Tags: mysql, node.js

This is a weird problem and I'm not sure what's going on. I installed MySQL on a linux box I have running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. I can access mysql via SSH `mysql -p` and perform all my commands that way. I added a user, and I can use `AddedUser` to connect remotely from my machine, but not from the local machine. It makes no sense to me...

`SELECT host, user FROM mysql.user` Yields:

```
+-----------+------------------+
| host      | user             |
+-----------+------------------+
| %         | AddedUser        |
| 127.0.0.1 | root             |
| li241-255 | root             |
| localhost | debian-sys-maint |
| localhost | root             |
+-----------+------------------+
```

Problem is I'm developing on this machine using Node.js, and I can't connect locally from the server using the same username. I've tried `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` but that seems to have no effect.

I know it's not Node.js because I'm using the same code on another database and it's working in that environment.

## **Edit**

This is the error node is giving me.

```
node.js:50
    throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
    ^
Error: ECONNREFUSED, Connection refused
    at Stream._onConnect (net.js:687:18)
    at IOWatcher.onWritable [as callback] (net.js:284:12)
```

## **Edit 2**

I have the right port & server as best I can tell. My `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` contains this:

```
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

My MySQL object contains:

```
{ host: 'localhost',
  port: 3306,
  user: 'removed',
  password: 'removed',
  database: '',
  typeCast: true,
  flags: 260047,
  maxPacketSize: 16777216,
  charsetNumber: 192,
  debug: false,
  ending: false,
  connected: false,
  _greeting: null,
  _queue: [],
  _connection: null,
  _parser: null,
  server: 'ExternalIpAddress' }
```

Possibly useful?

```
netstat -ln | grep mysql
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1016418  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Comment: Clarify "can't connect" please.

Comment: @A Wizard Did It: copy-paste error as-is please. If it **refuses connection** - then it is not related to users or previleges.

Comment: Ensure that you have the correct port in your connection setup in Node.js.

Comment: Updated the error coming from node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Connection Refused` is being signaled at the TCP/IP protocol level, and means that your local connection attempt is using the wrong hostname and/or (more likely) port number.

EDIT: Here's another (admittedly low-probability) possibility:

1. You have both `host` and `server` defined in the JS object, in which case node.js might give precedence to `server`.
2. If the `externalIPaddress` is on the other side of a NAT firewall, the firewall may be (actually, should be) configured to discard incoming traffic to port 3306.
3. When you try to connect, your packets are being routed to the NAT firewall first and are being discarded there.

Verify that having both `server` and `host` set will not cause this problem.

Comment: Added more info, maybe it will help.

Comment: Also do `netstat -nat|grep LISTEN` and see if 3306 is listed?

Comment: Yes, I have `tcp        0      0 MyExternalIpAddress:3306    0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     `

Comment: Well then, it's not listening on localhost:3306, only on the external IP address.  Change your mySql configuration to listen on both, or listen on 0.0.0.0

Comment: Wow... thank you... I feel like an idiot, but I'm glad I game to SO instead of spending a couple more hours trying to figure it out myself.

Comment: Don't feel bad... this type of thing is easy to miss, and all of us do it sometime.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the socketPath

```
mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'password',
    socketPath  : '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock',

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Manually defining the socket fixed this problem for me.

```
var client = mysql.createClient({
    user: '(your user here)',
    password: '(your password here)',
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: '3306',
    _socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock',
});
```

Comment: hey, how can i set "_socket" path when i try to connect with another server?

Comment: You will probably need to ssh into to the other server and find the location of the mysqld.sock file. If you don't have access to do that, I'm not sure, you'll have to find another library or another way to connect.

Comment: Hey, @Nick after a long suffer I found a answer just remove the "_socket" and replace the host with server ip address.

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar issues, but with MongoDB. I think you need to make your `host` point to `127.0.0.1` rather than `localhost`.

Check:

```
$ nslookup localhost
```

and

```
$ nslookup localhost.
```

both should return an address of 127.0.0.1

Also check `cat /etc/hosts`

if localhost maps to ipv6: `::1             localhost`
then change to `127.0.0.1 localhost`

`localhost` might be pointing to the ipv6 address rather than the ipv4 address.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

same problem.
i've just commented the line with **skip-networking** in  mysql config file, and the problem dissapeared

Answer (score 0):

As the first and good answer says, MySQL isn't listening to your local TCP/IP sockets.

Connect your `mysql.Client` module using:

> `client.port = '/tmp/mysql.sock';`

and fill in wherever your mysql socket file is located. If you can't find this, consider using this heavy but success-guaranteed system-wide search

> `cd / ; find * | grep mysql.sock`

Answer (score 0):

In my.cnf, I changed bind-address to 0.0.0.0 and now connections from my node app are correctly accepted.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this problem occurred on an Ubuntu box only accessible on our internal net (though I think this solution applies regardless of the network). I was able to access mysql perfectly well with mysql Workshop and with Node.js mysql plugin from my dev system but *not* from Node running on the server.

In particular, I tried localhost, 127.0.0.1 or even 'serverName', which was defined as 127... in /etc/hosts. I got nothing but ECONNREFUSED.

Turns out that my mysql instance was set to only accept connections addressed to the server's IP address. That is, it would only accept connections from

{host:'172.xxx.xxx.xxx', user:'blah', ....

Good luck!!