# felixge/node-mysql coudn't connect to database

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database-connection

I installed the [`felixge/node-mysql`](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) via npm (`npm install mysql`), and now i want to connect to the mysql database, but every time I try to connect this error happens:

```
{ [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect' }
undefined
```

my nodejs source:

```
var mysql = require("mysql")
var db = mysql.createClient({
    host:"localhost",
    user:"root",
    password:"root"
});

db.query("SELECT 1",function(err,result,fields){
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(result);
});
```

But i can easily access to my MySQL database via command line:

```
[user@host] $ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 4
Server version: 5.5.18-log Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> SELECT 1
    -> ;
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Can anybody help me what is my mistake?

Comment: You have a spelling mistake `console.log(results);` should read `console.log(result);`

Comment: the problem persists. btw thanks

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe the module doesn't like SELECTs without USEing a database. Try connecting to a db and then selecting.

Comment: so is your password for root, root?
Where can you log as root from.

Comment: i can login as root only from localhost, but yes my password is root.

Comment: it dosent matter is the query good or not. there is a connection error.

Comment: Don't believe everything you read.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Can Connect Remotely but not Locally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523459/mysql-can-connect-remotely-but-not-locally)

Comment: thanks to chat, somebody found an exact duplicate of my problem. and there was also an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523459/mysql-can-connect-remotely-but-not-locally#7640304

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to modify the mysql configuration file. I commented out `skip-networking` and it fixed my problem.

*If anybody can explain me why is that good I would thank it.*

Comment: Node-mysql assumes localhost:3306 by default. With skip-networking mysql only uses a unix socket (use `mysqladmin variables | grep sock` to find the location) and mysql-client can connect to that socket, while node code can't (it doesn't know the location). Use `socketPath` to specify the socket path and uncomment `skip-networking` for better mysql performance

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the socketPath

```
mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'password',
    socketPath  : '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock',

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I use MAMP on MacOSX, remember add this

**"socketPath": "/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock"**

```
{
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 3306,
    "user": "nodejs",
    "password": "nodejs",
    "database": "crawler",
    "socketPath": "/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you connect to mysql with node-mysql, you need to specify your hostname. If you're on linux you can find out using the command : **hostname**

So you know, i have the same problem i can connect to mysql via command line without specify the hostname but in node you need to change it. At least in my case. (v0.4.10) Why ? I'm not sure so maybe someone else have an idea.

```
var mysql = require("mysql")
var db = mysql.createClient({
    host: --- put what you got from the hostname command ---,
    user:"root",
    password:"root"
});
```