# How to connect to MySQL using node.js (with node-mysql driver)?

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I have the following code, which I am trying to run. I have given comments accordingly to mention what all I have tried.

```
// File saved as app.js
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host:'localhost',    //even tried with 127.0.0.1
    port:3306,           //confirmed port by looking into /etc/mysql/my.cnf has [client] port = 3306
    user:'root',         //credentials are verified since Php My Admin logs in with same
    password:'password' //credentials are verified since Php My Admin logs in with same
    //Even tried to connect using _socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
  // connected! (unless `err` is set)
  if(err)
    console.log(err); return;
});
```

Since the default port is not changed, the phpMyAdmin is working fine for me. But I am not able to connect using [node-mysql driver](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) from [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/).

The following is the error message I am getting:

```
amolkulkarni@ubuntu:~/Project/Node_MySQL$ node app.js
{ [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  fatal: true }
```

Could anyone please help on this?

---

**Update:** Based on comments

```
 amolkulkarni@ubuntu:~/ ps ax | grep mysqld
 5905 ?        S      0:00 sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking
 5906 ?        Sl     0:12 /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking
 28964 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
 29098 pts/3    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto mysqld
```

I am able to connect to mysql using `mysql -hlocalhost -uroot -ppassword` but if I replace with ip e.g. `mysql -h192.168.1.10 -uroot -ppassword` It gives error as follows:

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.3.78' (111)

Comment: I have already seen this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117005/nodejs-node-mysql-module-not-connecting-to-database). I didn't get the answer and its different question..

Comment: Can you connect using command line client? In your case, `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -ppassword`?

Comment: @AndreySidorov Thanks for your time. Its throwing error `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)`

Comment: Can you connect without "-h" key? Also, what is the output of "ps ax | grep mysqld"?

Comment: @AndreySidorov Now, I am able to connect using `mysql -hlocalhost -uroot -ppassword`. And updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your server is started with [--skip-networking](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-networking) flag:

> Do not listen for TCP/IP connections at all. All interaction with
>   mysqld must be made using named pipes or shared memory (on Windows) or
>   Unix socket files (on Unix). This option is highly recommended for
>   systems where only local clients are permitted.

Try to connect to unix socket or start server with TCP enabled.